# replacing the string values using grouping

Tags: javascript

I have url string, where i want insert one string and stitch it back together. I am able to add the first two set of strings but the last group I am not able to

```js
let string = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1/replace-text'
    .replace(/(\/\/[^\/]+)?\/.*/, '$1/testing/$2');
    
    console.log(string)
```

Here I want to attach the remaining part after the first slash which should be $2 but I am not able to achieve it. How can I achieve this what my expected output is

```
http://stackoverflow.com/testing/questions/1/replace-text
```

Comment: You only have one capture group, what is `$2` supposed to use?

Comment: Put a capture group around the remainder.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to match the rest of the URL. Just match the part you want to replace, and the rest will be kept in the replacement.

```js
let string = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1/replace-text'
    .replace(/\/\/[^\/]+/, '$&/testing');
    
    console.log(string)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use lookaheads to insert into the string without removing anything:

`(?<!:|\/)(?=\/)|$`

- The `(?<!:\/)` is a negative lookbehind to ignore the protocol header (://)
- The `(?=\/)` is a positive lookahead that checks for a single slash
- The `$` accounts for a string without a slash at the end

```js
const regex = /(?<!:|\/)(?=\/)|$/;

const testString = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1/replace-text';

console.log(testString.replace(regex, '/testing'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite a fancy solution but it works.

```js
let string = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1/replace-text'
// http://stackoverflow.com/testing/questions/1/replace-text
let parts = string.split("/")
let newString = parts[0] + "//"+ parts[2]  + "/testing/" +  parts[3] +"/" +  parts[4]  + "/" +   parts[5] 

console.log( newString , "newString" )
```